# System.Windows.Input.Cursors not complete?

Tags: c#, wpf

When setting the `Mouse.OverrideCursor` property you can choose from a list of Cursors. Arrow for example is contained in the `Cursors` class:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

But I'm missing the move and copy cursors, which usually appear during Drag&Drop. I know there is always the possiblity of creating a custom cursor, but I would not want to do that, when those cursors already exist.

How can I get those cursors?

Comment: The D+D cursors never belonged to the stock cursors on Windows.  Mostly a historical accident.  File > Open > File, select c:\windows\system32\ole32.dll.  Expand the Cursors node.  IDs 1, 2 and 3 are the standard D+D cursors.  Right-click > Export to save them to a .cur file.  Do keep in mind that they are *only* appropriate for D+D and already used when you use DragDrop.DoDragDrop() so maybe you are just not using the feature appropriately.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks this works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Move" cursor is called `Cursors.SizeAll` (which looks like sizing in all directions).

For moving drag'n'drop window (win 10), it actually looks like normal arrow.

Copy cursor is not one of basic and You need either load it from file or use the drawing of it as mentioned in topic below.

[Can I choose a custom image for C# Windows Application Drag Drop functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078211/can-i-choose-a-custom-image-for-c-sharp-windows-application-drag-drop-functions)