# DestroyIcon after SHGetFileInfo?

Tags: shell, winapi, memory-leaks, icons, handle

I'm using `SHGetFileInfo` to get the icon of specific file type. The MSDN says about the `SHFILEINFO`:

```
hIcon

    Type: HICON

    A handle to the icon that represents the file. You are responsible 
    for destroying this handle with DestroyIcon when you no longer 
    need it.
```

To get the icon from HIcon, I use `Icon.FromHandle`. Again, MSDN says:

```
Remarks
    When using this method, you must dispose of the original icon 
    by using the DestroyIcon method in the Win32 API to ensure 
    that the resources are released.
```

It is even more confusing as `SGHFI_ICON` description contains the following information:

```
SHGFI_ICON (0x000000100)

    Retrieve the handle to the icon that represents the file and the 
    index of the icon within the system image list. The handle is 
    copied to the hIcon member of the structure specified by psfi, 
    and the index is copied to the iIcon member.
```

From this description, it seems like the handle is kept by the OS and I shouldn't actually destroy it.

**My question is then**: if, and if so, when should I dispose of the icon handle?

- Immediately after `Icon.FromHandle()` ?
- When I no longer need the icon created from `Icon.FromHandle()` ? (in such case I guess that I'd rather copy the icon, release the original and return the copy to avoid handle leaks)
- Never (it will be done automatically somehow? Many examples of SHGetFileInfo - even on SO - does not include any code releasing the icon handle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system doesn't keep icon handles, it keeps image lists. When you use the `SHGFI_ICON` flag, `SHGetFileInfo` creates an icon by calling `ImageList_GetIcon` against the system image list. You can do this yourself by passing the `SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX` flag instead to retrieve just the icon index.

The icon should be destroyed when you're done with it.

Comment: Ok, I guess that means option 2?

Answer (score 3):

No, you really do have to call DestroyIcon yourself.  The Icon.FromHandle() method is pretty useless to help you with that, it *still* requires you to call DestroyIcon.  You've got to implement your own garbage collector code to *know* that the icon is no longer in use so it is safe to pinvoke DestroyIcon.

This is cruel and unusual punishment.  The Icon class does in fact have a constructor that can create an Icon object from a handle and *owns* the handle, automatically calling DestroyIcon when the Icon object is disposed or finalized.  They however made it inaccessible for unphantomable reasons, major bummer.  Reflection to the rescue, you can bypass this silly restriction and still use the constructor, find the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551567/17034).

Comment: Well, I guess, that my option 2 approach is also possible: get the handle, use Icon.FromHandle, copy it to bitmap or another icon, release the handle and return the copy. It's less efficient though.