# Get application icon path

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a project l. I need to get file icon path to use with another function.

The function requires a string as it's parameter and I am getting System.Drawing.Icon

I got icon from:

```
Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()
```

I thought of saving the icon as bitmap somewhere in the drive.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Any answers appreciated.

Comment: Is this a windows forms application ? What do you mean by "application icon", the icon of the form ? Or the icon of the assembly ? Or other icon ?

Comment: Application icon from desktop

Comment: If you can do the translation to c# yourself [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1551567/578411) from Hans Passant might be helpful.